# Create or Update is not returning updated value in GORM

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

Following is my model:

```
type Room struct {
    PK        string `sql:"size:255;not null;"gorm:"primary_key"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time

    LastSentMessageSeq int64
    RoomID             string `sql:"size:255;not null;"gorm:"unique_index:rooms_room_id_client_id"`
    User               User
    UserID             string `sql:"size:255;not null"`
    Client             Client
    ClientID           string `sql:"size:255;not null"gorm:"unique_index:rooms_room_id_client_id"`
}
```

I am using Postgres. I am trying to do update or create operation. If row exists, increment `LastSentMessageSeq` field or else insert a new one.  Following is my code:

```
var room = Room{ClientID: clientID, RoomID: roomID, UserID: usedID, LastSentMessageSeq: 10}
err := ws.db.Set("gorm:insert_option", "ON CONFLICT (room_id, client_id) DO UPDATE SET last_sent_message_seq = rooms.last_sent_message_seq + 1").Create(&room).Error
log.Println(err)
log.Println(room)
```

However, when I print the room object, it does not have the updated value for the field `LastSentMessageSeq`. But I can see it is doing upsert operation, i.e. it creates a new row if it does not exist or updates the value of LastSentMessageSeq in the database

Answer (score 0):

What you can do so that GORM will automatically pick it up (add `RETURNING` clause for the field) is by adding the `default` tag on the field. This is a bit hackish, but it works tho.

```golang
    LastSentMessageSeq int64 `gorm:"default:0"`
```